# Variable not defined when outside scope

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, random

Writing​ ​a​ ​program​ ​that​ ​lets​ ​the​ ​user​ ​throw​ ​five​ ​dice​ ​and​ ​to display​ ​the​ ​result​ ​“graphically”​ ​on​ ​the​ ​screen.
 The​ ​program​ ​should​ ​start​ ​by​ ​simulating​ ​five​ ​die​ ​throws​ ​by​ ​filling​ ​an​ ​array​ ​with​ ​5​ ​numbers between​ ​1​ ​and​ ​5.​ ​A function ​should​ ​then​ ​“draw”​ ​the​ ​result​ ​by​ ​displaying​ ​characters​ ​on​ ​the​ ​screen and a function who calculate the sum.
I get a error message the first function, it says I have not defined the matrix, which I defined in the "if".

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int sumOfDie(int inputArray[], int arraySize); 
int drawDie(int inputArray[], int arraySize)
{
int i, row, column=0;

for (i=0; i<arraySize; i++)  //determine the graphic number from the random number
{
    if (inputArray[i]==1)
    {
        char matrix [3][4] = {{"   "},{" * "},{"   "}};
    }
    if (inputArray[i]==2)
    {
        char matrix [3][4] = {{"*  "},{"   "},{"  *"}};
    }
    if (inputArray[i]==3)
    {
        char matrix [3][4] = {{"*  "},{" * "},{"  *"}};
    }
    if (inputArray[i]==4)
    {
        char matrix [3][4] = {{"* *"},{"   "},{"* *"}};
    }
    if (inputArray[i]==5)
    {
        char matrix [3][4] = {{"* *"},{" * "},{"* *"}};
    }

    for (row=0; row<3; row++) //Print out the matrix
    {
        for(column=0; column<4; column++)
        {
            printf("%c     ", matrix[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

}
int sumOfDie(int inputArray[], int arraySize) 
{
    int i, sum=0;
    for (i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
    {
        sum=sum+inputArray[i];
    }
    return sum;
}



int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int inputArry[5];
    srand(time(NULL)); 


for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    inputArry[i] = rand()%5+1;
}

for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    printf("Number:%d\n", inputArry[i]);
}

drawDie(inputArry, 5);

sum = sumOfDie(inputArray,5)
printf("The sum of %i + %i + %i + %i + %i = %i", inputArry[0], inputArry[1], inputArry[2], inputArry[3], inputArry[4], sum);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your mistake is because `char matrix` is defined inside the `if` scope statement. After leaving the if scope, the variable does not exist anymore. Try to define the array outside the `for` loop. Nonetheless, you are declaring `matrix` as a char, but you are trying to store a string instead of a single char.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec80ebb03d022a80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `drawDie`, the scope of each of the variables named `matrix` is limited to the `if` statement where they are declared, so that they can't be used later to be printed.

You can collect all the strings needed to represent the dices in a single multidimentional array and then print the ones you need.

This is a possible implementation (considering a six sided dice):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_n_times_in_a_row(const char *str, int n)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
        printf(" %s", str); 
    }
    puts("");
}

void draw_dices(int* values, int n)
{
    static const char dice_str[][3][8] = {
        {{"       "},{"   *   "},{"       "}},  // 1
        {{" *     "},{"       "},{"     * "}},  // 2
        {{" *     "},{"   *   "},{"     * "}},  // ...
        {{" *   * "},{"       "},{" *   * "}},
        {{" *   * "},{"   *   "},{" *   * "}},
        {{" *   * "},{" *   * "},{" *   * "}}   // 6. Just in case...
    };

    // I'll print all the "dices" in a row   
    print_n_times_in_a_row("+-------+", n);
    for ( int j = 0; j < 3; ++j )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        {
            printf(" |%s|", dice_str[values[i] - 1][j]); 
        }
        puts("");
    }
    print_n_times_in_a_row("+-------+", n);
}


int main(void)
{
    int dices[] = {4, 2, 5, 6, 1, 3};

    draw_dices(dices, 6);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
 +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-------+
 | *   * | | *     | | *   * | | *   * | |       | | *     |
 |       | |       | |   *   | | *   * | |   *   | |   *   |
 | *   * | |     * | | *   * | | *   * | |       | |     * |
 +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not declared a conditional array even if the array is always created
you should just declare your array before if statement `char matrix [3][4];`

After leaving the if scope, the variable does not exist anymore

Answer (score -1):

The solution to make your code work is like this, you can use a switch case to distinguish what do you want to print on screen. The `array` only store the index to be used in the switch.

What you did wrong was about where you declared the `array` inside the scope of the `if` statement, so, once the block inside `if` is executed the `array` does not exist anymore.

Also, the problem about how do you think in storing data inside the `char array`, you need to specify the sides in advance (at runtime is also possible in C99 but let's skip that), or dynamically allocate it (which is not necessary here).

So, `char var` can store a single byte, but you were trying to store a string `{"    "}`, so you get error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int sumOfDie(int inputArray[], int arraySize);
int drawDie(int inputArray[], int arraySize)
{
    int i, row, column=0;

    char matrix[5][5];
    for (i=0; i<arraySize; i++)  //determine the graphic number from the random number
    {
        if (inputArray[i]==1)
        {
            matrix [3][4] = 0; //{{"   "},{" * "},{"   "}};
        }
        if (inputArray[i]==2)
        {
            matrix [3][4] = 1; //{{"*  "},{"   "},{"  *"}};
        }
        if (inputArray[i]==3)
        {
            matrix [3][4] = 2; //{{"*  "},{" * "},{"  *"}};
        }
        if (inputArray[i]==4)
        {
            matrix [3][4] = 3; //{{"* *"},{"   "},{"* *"}};
        }
        if (inputArray[i]==5)
        {
            matrix [3][4] = 4; //{{"* *"},{" * "},{"* *"}};
        }

        for (row=0; row<3; row++) //Print out the matrix
        {
            for(column=0; column<4; column++)
            {
                switch (matrix[row][column]) {
                    case 0:
                        // change the print accordingly
                        printf("    *     \n");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // change the print accordingly
                        printf("    *     \n");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // change the print accordingly
                        printf("    *     \n");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        // change the print accordingly
                        printf("    *     \n");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        // change the print accordingly
                        printf("    *     \n");
                        break;
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

}

int sumOfDie(int inputArray[], int arraySize)
{
    int i, sum=0;
    for (i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
    {
        sum=sum+inputArray[i];
    }
    return sum;
}



int main(void)
{
    int i, sum;
    int inputArray[5];
    srand(time(NULL));


    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        inputArray[i] = rand()%5+1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("Number:%d\n", inputArray[i]);
    }

    drawDie(inputArray, 5);

    sum = sumOfDie(inputArray,5);
    printf("The sum of %i + %i + %i + %i + %i = %i", inputArray[0], inputArray[1], inputArray[2], inputArray[3], inputArray[4], sum);
}
```

Comment: this is quite hideous, and also quite buggy.