# Use char array instead of char name when printing array C

Tags: c

This is a function in my code.

```
int grafik(void){
   char ett[3][6]={{"   "},{" * "},{"   "}};

   char c[] = "ett";

   printf("%c ", c[][3][6]);

   return 0;
}
```

So basically I want to use the charter array c[] instead of typing "ett" when printing this array. Why I want to do this is because I will have many arrays with exactly the same size so to save code I want to use the array c[] containing the name of the array to be printed using only one for loop to print array instead of using 36 for loops needed if every array and possibility need its own print loop. Note that the print loop is not included in this code.

```
//What I need to do to print part of the array ett
printf("%c ", ett[3][6]);
//What I want to do to print part of the array ett
printf("%c ", c[][3][6]);
```

Comment: `printf("%c ", c[][3][6]);` is really not valid.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the precise problem you are trying to solve ? Your use case ?

Comment: Note that `printf("%c ", ett[3][6]);` is indexing out of the array bounds, the max indexing allowed is `ett[2][5]`. But did you mean to write `printf("%s ", ett[2]);` ?

Comment: If by `c[][3][6]`, if you thought you were implementing  a variable variable as you see in languages like `php` (check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)), you don't have that in `C`. Time to start with a good `C` book.

Comment: *"I will have many arrays with exactly the same size"*, so you can add a dimension and use a 3D array...

Comment: How do I make a 3d array? Basically I am building a dice in console where char ett[3][6]={{"   "},{" * "},{"   "}}; is the side of a dice with one dot. I will then add more similar arrays for the other sides of dice

Comment: Well, if that is your problem, forgive me for the shameless plug, but I think that this answer of mine may be related to your actual task: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47514034/4944425

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to access array `ett` indirectly via array `c`, by recording `ett`'s *name* in `c`.  That will not work at all in C.  But you can do something similar by making `c` a *pointer* to an array:

```
int grafik(void){
   char ett[3][6]={{"   "},{" * "},{"   "}};

   char (*c)[6] = ett;  // c is a pointer to an array of 6 char,
                        // initially pointing to the first element of ett
   printf("%s ", *c);

   // Also:
   printf("%s ", c[0]);
   printf("%s ", c[1]);
   printf("%s ", c[2]);

   // And
   for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
       for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
           printf("%c ", c[row][col]);
       }
       putchar('\n');
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Pointers are C's mechanism for indirection.